# Displaying the surveyjs results in a web page

Tags: json, display, surveyjs

I have my surveyjs results stored in a database. Each survey response has been stored in a string json-like format. Now I want to display it back in a read-only (or editable) form like the original one on a web page.
I'm using ASP.NET and Angular
How could I achieve that?
Thanks

Nothing yet. I have no idea

Answer (score 0):

You have an array of JSONs. You can place them into a data grid. We use [tabulator table](https://tabulator.info/). You can configure it by yourself. It works with JSONs array. If you have just one survey and results for it then it is not a big deal.

If you have many surveys/forms, then you may look at our implementation. Here is [the example](https://surveyjs.io/dashboard/examples/export-survey-results-to-csv-files) with table. Please note, it is part of our [Dashboard](https://surveyjs.io/dashboard) product, and unlike [SurveyJS Library](https://surveyjs.io/form-library) that is under MIT license, it is under a [commercial license](https://surveyjs.io/pricing).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But what I'm looking for is to display the answers (results) in a format of the initial questionnaire with the questions and answers.

Comment: Do you mean show the survey in read-only mode with pre-loaded data? Here is the example: https://surveyjs.io/form-library/examples/enable-protected-view-mode